# Beautifulsoup soup.body return None

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

What can cause beautifulsoup to return `soup.body` as `None` knowing that `soup.title` returns the expected result

here is the link of the page i'm parsing http://goo.gl/6T3RKV

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

gives the exact html of the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the [differences in `BeautifulSoup` parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers):

```
>>> from urllib2 import urlopen
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = 'http://www.emploi.ma/offre-emploi-maroc/commerciaux-en-emission-appels-1019077'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html5lib")
>>> print soup.body
None

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "html.parser")
>>> print soup.body
<body class="not-front not-logged-in page-node node-type-offre no-sidebars candidate-context full-node layout-main-last sidebars-split font-size-12 grid-type-960 grid-width-16 role-other" id="pid-node-1019077">
<div class="page" id="page">
... 

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "lxml")
>>> print soup.body
<body class="not-front not-logged-in page-node node-type-offre no-sidebars candidate-context full-node layout-main-last sidebars-split font-size-12 grid-type-960 grid-width-16 role-other" id="pid-node-1019077">
<div class="page" id="page">
...
```

As you can see, `html5lib` cannot get the `body` from this particular html. And, according to the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use), `html5lib` would be chosen as a default in case `lxml` is not installed:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s
>   installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then
>   html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

Comment: thank you soooooooooooooooooooo much !! maan you saved me from spending so many hours on this !